# Output Full File Path to HTML with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am creating a test list in Doxygen using the \test special command. I understand that I can click on the class name for that section and get taken through to the page that this test is in reference too.

What I would like however is in the test description for it to have a line which is the full file path.

Is there a special command to do this? or do I have to physically type it out into every comment block. below I have shown an example of what I want.

```
Class myTest
    Perform a set of tests to verify foo & bar.
    located in C:\MyFile
```

but I would like to write out my Doxygen comment like this:

```
/** \test
 *   Perform a set of tests to verify foo & bar.
 *   located in:
 *   \fullFilePath
 */
```

Is this possible?

Comment: There is no command \fullFilePath, there is the configuration option FULL_PATH_NAMES and SHOW_USED_FILES but I think they do not do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having scoured the special commands I've come to the conclusion that there is no Doxygen special command to give the result as in the question.

Doxygen does provide automatic hyperlinking for pages/files that it knows exist. Therefore in order to "solve" this problem<sup>[1]</sup> I have added the minimal amount of path name that is required in order to create a navigatable link. This solution looks like:

```
/** \test
 *   Perform a set of tests to verify foo & bar.
 *   located in:
 *   someFolder/myFile.cpp
 */
```

This would work for a file path like: `C:/parentFolder/childFolder/someFolder/myFile.cpp`

---

<sup>[1]</sup> The original question was focused around not having to type out the filepath into every comment block. This solution is a compromise between not having a special command and not having to write out the complete file path (which sometimes could be very long)